# Finder Search does not work after migrating to 2022 MB Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Finder Search does not work after migrating from MB Pro 2016 to MB Pro 2022. Search only works for "This Mac," but anything outside of that returns zero results. Please help, thank you.
[image]

Comment: What about Command Space Spotlight search? So searching "This Mac" will return files in the Downloads folder, but selecting "Downloads" shows no results?

Comment: That is correct. What to do?